# AngularJS Cannot access variable difference file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new in AngularJs. I just started learning dependencies concept.but i got problem when separated file between `app.js` and `formapp.js`. I cannot access `users` variable because its separated files.How can i access the variable?.I hope you guys can help me solve this problem.Thank you in advance.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="training">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="formapp.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" />
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="UserController as usersCtrl">

    <h3>User Information</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="user in usersCtrl.mUsers">
        <p><ul>
            <li>{{user.name}}</li>
            <li>{{user.age}}</li>
            <li>{{user.occupation}}</li>
        </ul></p>
    </div> 

    <form-Directive></form-Directive>

  </body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
(function(){

    var app = angular.module('training',['form']);


    app.controller('UserController',function(){

        this.mUsers = users;
    });

    var users = [{
        name:"michael",
        age:"27",
        occupation:"business"
    },{
        name:"john",
        age:"25",
        occupation:"police"
    }];

})();
```

**formapp.js**

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module("form",[]);
        app.directive('formDirective', function(){
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'user-form-directive.html',
            controller:function(){
                this.newUser = {};

                this.addUser = function(){
                    users.push(this.newUser);      //<-- users is not defined
                    this.newUser = {};
                };
            },
            controllerAs: 'formCtrl'
        };
    });
})();
```

Comment: You should just pass the users in to your directive via attribute binding, otherwise you're going to end up creating a circular dependency between the two modules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass **mUsers** as an attribute to your element directive -  **formDirective**.

**index.html**

```
<form-Directive users='mUsers'></form-Directive>
```

**formapp.js**

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module("form",[]);
    app.directive('formDirective', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'user-form-directive.html',
        scope: {
           users: '='
        },
        controller:['$scope', function($scope){
            this.newUser = {};

            this.addUser = function(){
                $scope.users.push(this.newUser);      //<-- users is not defined
                this.newUser = {};
            };
        }]
    };
});
})();
```